# Computation of a certain flux integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let
$$\Omega = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \max(|x|_1, |x|_2, |x|_3) \leq 1\}$$
$$F_i(x) = \frac{x_i}{\|x\|^3}$$
and suppose $\varphi(y)$ be a continuously differentiable function of $y_i = x_i/\|x\|$,
with $\varphi$ having average value $1$ over the unit sphere.

Calculate
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi F \cdot n \; dS$$

The solution I get is zero by the divergence theorem. But this is not what the solution manual says. Am I wrong, or is the solution manual wrong? I never use the assumption on
the average value of $\varphi$.

Comment: $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{F}$ is singular at $\vec{x} = 0$. You cannot apply divergence theorem to the whole $\Omega$. Instead, you need to apply it to $\Omega \setminus \{ \vec{0} \}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^3}$, then $\mathrm{d}\sigma=\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,\mathrm{d}S$ is the differential solid angle. The solid angle surface integral of a function over an arbitrary region is then equal to the surface integral over the unit sphere

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial\Omega}\phi\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} &=\oint_{\partial\Omega}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=\oint_{S_2}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=4\pi\cdot\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint_{S_2}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=4\pi,
\end{align}$$

where in the last line we've used the given information that the average value of $\phi$ over the unit sphere is $\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint_{S_2}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\sigma=1$.